# Is there a size limit to a MBTiles file?

Tags: java, android, osmdroid

We recently upgraded the map file in our offline app to support an extra zoom level, but now the app can't find the resource in the raw folder.

The previous map was around 550MB.

The new one is 1.2GB.

The app crashes at this line now:

```
InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.fire_map);
```

With this line in the logcat:`java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{org.ir.mobilemap/org.ir.mobilemap.IRMobileMapActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/raw/fire_map.mbtiles from drawable resource ID #0x7f060003`

I tested it multiple times and I can't find the problem, reverting to the old map works perfectly fine. Is there any restriction I am not aware of, or is the problem somewhere else?

Comment: there isn't from an osmdroid perspective, you may be hitting the ceiling for APK files in raw though. I did notice that MOBAC makes 1GB max Mbtiles db. Consider using sqlite?

Comment: @spy I never used MOBAC, and I am pretty sure I am using SQLite.

Comment: @spy Could the problem be when the file is being generated from TileMill?

Comment: it's possible, but I think the issue is the size of the file in the APK, try copying it to /sdcard/osmdroid and see if it works.

Comment: I will try this tommorow and come back with feedback.

Comment: @spy You were right! Having a 1GB file in the APK seems to cause problems, but an APK over 100MB is already not good practice so I guess that's why I couldn't find the reason. Feel free to answer the question. :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably hitting the ceiling for maximum file size within an APK. You may be able to compile and package it, but reading it may not work.

A few solutions:

- Reduce the database size
- Copy the contents of the file from raw to local storage at application bootup, then access the database(s) from the file system. This won't work in your case since you can't open the file
- Download the database to local storage after your app is installed.

Comment: In a licensed app on the play store scenario, the extra data ('.obb') would be downloaded after the '.apk' install. I didn't want to go further into that at the development level but looks like I will have to dive in.